# describe() from psych package not providing full descriptives

Tags: r, psych, describe

I need the full descriptives including all the moments, but when I use describe() from psych package, it doesn't give me the options I specify, for example skew and kurtosis, but it gives me all the deciles which I haven't specified for.

Can't figure out what the issue is.  Anyone else had this issue and know how to solve?  I know I can get skew and kurtosis using skew()and kurtosis() but I want all the describes in one call, not item by item.

Here's my code:

> s3desc <- describe(shrimp3s, skew = TRUE, ranges = TRUE, type = 1, quant = NULL, fast = NULL, IQR = TRUE)
>
> s3desc

What I get is:

**>  13  Variables      95  Observations

> -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- pond.sqm 
>          n  missing distinct     Info     Mean      Gmd      .05      .10      .25      .50      .75      .90      .95 
>         95        0       42    0.986     3227     1559     1000     1000     2047     3500     4300     4560     5157
>
> lowest :  800 1000 1100 1200 1450, highest: 5290 5400 5500 5700 5840
>   --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------**

Answer (score 0):

You have fallen into the multiple packages problem.  You are actually running the describe function from Hmisc.

Try loading the psych package and then describe(shrimp)

Or, if you need to have the Hmisc package active, specify which describe you want.

```
psych::describe(shrimp)
```